# Problemas ao conectar o php ao postgresql remotamente

Tags: php, postgresql, conexão

Estou tentando conectar remotamente o postgreSQL ao PHP em um servidor Apache. Na minha máquina local eu consigo executar a conexão sem nenhum problema. A questão é que não está funcionando remotamente.

Estou rodando o mesmo código que rodava em outra instância do mesmo serviço *cloud* (mudando apenas o IP). Não está aparecendo nenhuma mensagem de erro e não aparece a mensagem do código que indica que a base de dados não foi conectada. Estou usando um servidor Ubuntu 14.04. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Eu não estou conseguindo encontrar o problema!

**Checado:**

- Configuração na MV do postgresql pelo psql através de conexão SSH e o PgAdmin3 de forma remota. Ambos funcionando perfeitamente.
- Definição do password ok.
- Configuração do pg_hba.conf (conforme indicado no tutorial do serviço de cloud contratado)

> # IPv4 remote connections (all users and IP addresses): host all all
>   0.0.0.0/0 md5

- Configuração do postgresql.conf (conforme indicado no tutorial do serviço de cloud contratado)

  ```
  listen_addresses = '*'
  ```
- Regras de firewall - ok.
- Código PHP (o mesmo código funciona na máquina local perfeitamente e funcionava em uma outra instância do mesmo serviço de nuvem).

  ```
  <?php 

     $host        = "host=xx.xx.xx.xx";

     $port        = "port=5432";

     $dbname      = "dbname=nomedabasededados";

     $credentials = "user=postgres password=senha";

     $db = pg_connect( "$host $port $dbname $credentials"  );

     if(!$db){
        echo "Error : Unable to open database\n";
     } 

   $sql = pg_query("INSERT INTO tabela (coluna1) VALUES ('valordacoluna1');");     

  ?>
  ```

Comment: Tentou verificar se a porta está aberta, a partir de outro servidor?

Comment: Caro @Andre Mesquita, agradeço muito pela dica. Como eu poderia verificar se a porta está aberta? Eu consigo inserir os dados diretamente do meu psql ou pgadmin3, isso indica que a porta 5432 está aberta?

Comment: Caro @AndreMesquita, através do comando nmap eu obtive: 22/tcp, 80/tcp hhtp, 5432/tcp to postgresql. O senhor saberia me indicar como posso verificar a partir de outro servidor?

Comment: nmap mesmo. ao invés de usar localhost, usa o IP do seu servidor postgresql. Se tiver o ping bloqueado, pode usar o parametro -nP.

Comment: Caro @AndreMesquita, consegui verificar com o comando que o senhor me indicou. Obtive que as portas 22 (ssh), 80 (http) e 5432 (postgresql) estão abertas e as portas 443 (https) e 3389 (ms-wbt-server) estão fechadas. O senhor acredita que uma das portas fechadas pode estar prejudicando a conexão com o postgres?

Comment: Não. Não me recordo bem de postgresql, mas no mysql o usuário possui uma designação que indica se ele pode ser acessado de fora. Dá uma olhada neste [Artigo](https://pt.wikibooks.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Pr%C3%A1tico/Configura%C3%A7%C3%B5es/Configurar_acessos) que pode te orientar.

Comment: Tem esse outro [artigo](https://www.oficinadanet.com.br/artigo/2101/liberando_conexoes_remotas_ao_postgresql) que o rapaz explica sobre as permissões. Espero que ajude.

Comment: Obrigado @AndreMesquita

Comment: qual o serviço cloud ?